# WPF: view that scales to container at large sizes, scrolls at small sizes?

Tags: wpf, layout, scroll, size, containers

I am building a control depicting a diagram. The control's content (which is rather complex) will try to scale to fit allotted space to the extent possible. However, not all scales are valid. The content cannot shrink indefinitely. E.g. a box on a diagram should be at least 20 pixels wide. Thus, when the window is too small to fit the content even at the minimum size, scaling should stop and scroll bars must appear.

I cannot find an elegant solution for this in WPF. Any design ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Horizontal` & `VerticalAlignment` of the content to `Stretch` but also set the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` to appropriate values, place your content in a `ScrollViewer` whose `Horizontal` & `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is set to `Auto`.

That should work, probably...

Example:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Button
            MinHeight="400"
            MinWidth="400"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Content="Buttons!"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes, you understood my question just right. I cannot use your example directly, since I have Panels and some measurement involved, but your answer made me realize this: when your panel is in a scroll viewer, upon measurement you calculate minimum possible size that lets you survive, while upon arrangement you use up the space provided. Thus, you calculate your layout twice. Seems obvious ones it's stated, but I did not get it the first time. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :) There are some interesting articles on MSDN by the way, e.g. [Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) & [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx).